# How to read merged cells from .xls file using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have an excel sheet I'm trying to read in python using pandas. It has some vertically merged cells. the problem is **when reading merged cells, Nan is displayed for them after the first cell. **

Here i am reading the first column "Mr. rattandeepanjea" 
[image]

The output comes like this with Nan for merged cells, note timeslot 11:20-12:45
[image]

My code is:

```
 import pandas as pd
 xls = pd.ExcelFile("third.xls") #open the file
 sheetX = xls.parse(0)   #move to sheet number 1
 colAneja = sheetX["MR. RATTAN DEEP ANEJA"]
 counter = 9  #the counter is just for showing timeslots out of a list
 for lecture in colAneja:
    print(lisTime[counter%9],": ",lecture)
    counter+=1
```

`
I would expect the same values for all merged cells, like in this case:

```
10:55-11:50 - DS LAB(G2) MCA-1(RDA)
11:50-12:45 - DS LAB(G2) MCA-1(RDA)
```

Comment: What value would you expect there instead of `nan`?

Comment: The same values for all the merged cells instead of nan, say if 3 merged cells have value xyz, 
then xyz, xyz, xyz for all the three individual cells.

Answer (score 2):

simple

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: This only works if there aren't "legitimate" `nan` values, which it appears there will be from the screenshot

Comment: @asongtoruin hey thanks for pointing that out..i think in that situtation either he will have to to forward fill for half and backward fill for the other half..other might be to loop but that needs assumption that i wont be getting more than some number of empty cells...do tell if you find any other